# Specifying index at scale in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am trying to `orderByChild` see some sample data below.

```
    {
        "teams": {
            "blue":{
                "tomsmith":{
                    "firstName":"Tom",
                    "lastName":"Smith",
                    "sortTotal":-433,
                    "total":433
                },
                "bobsmith":{
                    "firstName":"Bom",
                    "lastName":"Smith",
                    "sortTotal":-133,
                    "total":133
                }
            },
            "red":{
                "tomkelly":{
                    "firstName":"Tom",
                    "lastName":"Kelly",
                    "sortTotal":-1433,
                    "total":1433
                },
                "davekelly":{
                    "firstName":"Dave",
                    "lastName":"Kelly",
                    "sortTotal":-99,
                    "total":99
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I view the console I am getting the below message.

`FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "sortTotal" at /teams/blue to your security rules for better performance.`

I can fix this issue by adding the below to my security rules file.

```
"teams": {
    "blue": {".indexOn": "sortTotal"},
    "red": {".indexOn": "sortTotal"}
}
```

But what if I have lots of teams or what if my application allows the users to add their own team?
How can I handle this?

Can you globally set an index? eg for this database I want an index set on all nodes with the `sortTotal` field. Or can you do it at the parent level eg

```
"teams": {".indexOn": "sortTotal"}
```

would also apply down to all team nodes without individually specifying? (I tried this and it didn't seem to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering and indexing only work one wild-card level down. Since you define an index for `sortTotal` on `/teams`, it will only index the `sortTotal` value for `/teams/red` and `/teams/blue`.

As usual with NoSQL databases this means that you need to change (or augment) your data structure to fit the needs of your application. It's a bit unclear what your current use-case is, but I can see these:

1. what team has the player with the highest `sortTotal`?
2. what player across all teams has the highest `sortTotal`?
3. what player on team `red` has the highest `sortTotal`?

### what team has the player with the highest `sortTotal`?

For case 1, you could add a `highSortTotalValue` and `highestSortTotalPlayer` to each team.

```
"teams": {
    "blue":{
        "highSortTotalValue":-433,
        "highestSortTotalPlayer": "tomsmith"
    },
    "red":{
        "highSortTotalValue":-1433,
        "highestSortTotalPlayer": "tomkelly"
    }
}
```

You could index this on `/teams` and then query `ref.child('teams').orderByChild('highSortTotalValue').on(...`.

### what player across all teams has the highest `sortTotal`?

If you want to know the sort total for players across all teams, you'll want to keep a list of those values for each player:

```
"playerSortTotals": {
    "tomsmith": -433,
    "tomkelly": -1433,
    "bomsmith": -133,
    "davekelly": -99
}
```

Now you can add an index to `/playerSortTotals` and find the highest sort total with `ref.child('playerSortTotals').orderByValue()...`

### what player on team `red` has the highest `sortTotal`?

This is possible with your current data structure. First you'll need to add an index to the each team:

```
"teams": { 
  "$teamid": {
    "$playerid": {
      ".indexOn": "sortTotal"
    }
  }
}
```

This index is populated for each team and contains the `sortTotal` for each player of that team.

With this index in place, you can query with `ref.child('teams/red').orderByChild('sortTotals')`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I was hoping to order each level by `sortTotal`, eg if you got to /red/users in the app it would display a list of the red users in order (`sortTotal`).  I might take your advice and restructure my data.

Comment: Ah, that is possible too. I had that use-case as #2, but explained another. I'll update and add a third.

Comment: Thats what I was hoping to be able to do thanks, sorry the initial question wasn't clear enough, but good to have the other two options you listed as a reference for the future.